# How to create an upload form with upload and custom filename in PHP?

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to create an upload form in PHP. Containing, upload input, text input (name to be given to the file that was uploaded), and submit button. However I don't know much about PHP, so I don't know how to actually link that what I had typed on the `<input type="text"/>` becomes the name of the file when uploaded.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tu peux uploader ici ta video.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="text" name="file-name"></input><br />  <!-- [ASK]: How to make this the file name of the uploaded file -->
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?PHP
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
​
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: How you access normal form fields after submission in PHP, is something you can go read up on in basically any beginner tutorial, in case you should still not know. And the target name of the file is set in the `move_uploaded_file` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination ) takes filename which is the filename of the uploaded file and destination is the destination of the moved file. Note that destination directory must exist; move_uploaded_file() will not automatically create it. So lets get the name now...

- $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'] gives you the temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server eg. C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\phpD3C.tmp
  while
- $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'] gives you the actual name which you need to extract the extension  eg. myfile.jpg
- To link  that what you had typed on the , first get it via $_POST["file-name"], then concatenate with the extension. Use pathinfo to retrieve the original extension.

Change your code to become...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tu peux uploader ici ta video.</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="text" name="file-name"></input><br />  <!-- [ASK]: How to make this the file name of the uploaded file -->
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $file_parts = pathinfo(basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])); //access the actual name instead of tmp_name
    //just pick the extension of the file_parts and concatenate it to your path
    $path = 'images/';
    $path = $path . $_POST["file-name"] . "." . $file_parts['extension'] ;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ". basename($path) ." has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

This should get you the desired name. So if you upload file dog.php and in the text field you have cow, the resulting name should be cow.php.

Result:
[image]

Comment: let me know if this answers your query. Also remember  to mark my answer as correct if it works. Thanks.

Comment: almost there thanks. The only thing is that when I finally move it to the `$path`. I'm losing the file extension of that particular file.

Comment: Now you are there. I have edited my answer, see above. Thank you.